# Getting the decimal value from front half of another's binary?

Tags: c++, binary

Is there an easy way to do this without needing to convert the value to a binary string, chopping it in half, and re-converting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to give you the exact code (to let you get some practice), but what you need should be as simple as a binary shift right (>>).

If the number of bits is variable, you would need to calculate the integer base-2 logarithm of the number first to determine the binary "length". There are quite a few ways to do this efficiently, just make sure to use integers for the calculation (not float or double)!

Comment: Finding the binary length isn't so trivial

Comment: @john Ah, I was thinking along the lines of BCD. In case the number of bits varies you would need to take the base-2 logarithm of the number (the binary "length") and shift by half of that.